# Saving user decisions in cookies

Tags: javascript, json, cookies

I have a popup on my website that informs you about cookies. It is possible to see the list of vendors and accept each of them. The popup has two buttons: Accept and Reject. How to save (acceptance or rejection) the user's decision (including accepted vendors) as one cookie? Vendors data is taken from json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are edveloping a website that uses cookies, you should set up 2 function, one to *set cookies*, and one to *get them* by name.

```
function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
  var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
```

Now you can set a cookie like "preferences" or any other:

```
let cookiePref = "accepted"; //Or bool, or int
let daysToExists = 31; //how many days cookie will be valid
setCookie('cookiePreference', cookiePref, daysToExists);
```

Cookie will be named "cookiePreference", value will be a string "accepted", and will be valid for 31 days

Then, you can retrieve it:

```
pref = getCookie('cookiePreference');
```

If it was a string, To check if the cookie exist you can do

```
pref = getCookie('cookiePreference');
if (pref.length > 0) {
   // Cookie is setted
}
```

In this way, you can also set up a cookie in javascript and get back in php (as unsafe value) and vice-versa (as safe value)

Comment: Tkank you very much for this! But still, how do I retrieve the user's decision about which vendors he has accepted?

Comment: You can setup a cookie for each vendor.
ie:
setCookie('bmw', false, 31);
setCookie('audi', true, 31);
setCookie('ffiat', false, 31);
setCookie('ferrari', true, 31);

The way to cycle into vendors, depend if it's array or object.
Could be achieved with for, foreach, etc

Comment: If you want just one cookie, you can change the logic to: setCookie("preferences", "audi:false, fiat:true, ferrari:false", 31). And when you get it, you split the array.